# In VS Code, how do you make IntelliSense show all object keys without typing a character?

Tags: typescript, parameters, intellisense

In my example I'm using TypeScript, so let's say I have a TypeScript Interface like this:

```
interface Item {
  name: string,
  qty: number,
  price: number
}
```

When I go to implement this, I start typing something like this:

```
const item = <Item>{

}
```

now, with the current behavior I would type in a character, and IntelliSense will popup with some suggested parameters that have that character in it, for example if I enter `e` it will pop up with `name` and `price` but not qty for obvious reasons.

So I sometimes forget all the parameters, and I find myself hitting a random letter on my keyboard hoping that the parameter I'm trying to remember contains that character.

Is there any way to make it so when I open up those brackets, or hover over them, it just shows me ALL the parameters for this Interface?

Comment: Ctrl-space will do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try Ctrl+space.

From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense:

> You can trigger IntelliSense in any editor window by typing Ctrl+Space or by typing a trigger character (such as the dot character (.) in JavaScript).

Comment: When you extend an interface like `HTMLElement`, how do you make your own properties show up first? I'm currently ending up Intellisense suggesting a mostly alphabetical list of more than 277 properties, with my own properties alphabetically sorted in.

Comment: @connexo Maybe you can try to play with the [Locality Bonus](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_locality-bonus) by setting `"editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,` or the `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,` (or `false`) in your settings?

Answer (score 14):

The default shortcut for me was cmd+I:

[image]

[image]
Good luck!

Comment: Good luck to you too!

Answer (score 3):

CTRL+Space for Windows, or Control+Space for Mac.

This opens the list for all the proper components you can use for the place where the cursor is.

Comment: This is incorrect for Mac. Command + Space launches Spotlight Search. Ctrl + Space works for Mac as well.

Comment: @Chaos Ah, I forgot I was using a normal keyboard on Mac which does change some of the bindings since Windows has no Command and Mac uses Command for some of the commands where Windows uses CTRL.

Answer (score 1):

For me on mac it was: fn+ctrl+space

Comment: For me too, thanks for pointing this out. Wouldn't have found out otherwise

Answer (score 0):

In Linux(in my example, Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop), you can use "Ctrl+i" to get the available options pop up automatically.